# Project Resource Organization and Structure at Cocos2d-X Development

Tags: file-structure, cocoa

Cocos2d-X is a game engine framework based on Cocos2d-iPhone, which consists of expanding supported platforms, with multiple choice of programming languages thats shares the same API structure.

What is be better Project Resource Organization and Structure at Cocos2d-X Development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, to organize the resource **depend on the type of your game,** and the animation editor & UI editor and other tools you use.

I'm doing my first cocos2d-x project.  Here is how I deal with the resources.

- I'm using the texturepacker to generate the plists.
- I'm using the lua script to transform my old UI description file to new ones, and define new data structures and writing new Readers which cocos2d-x can support (something like cocos builder).
- Each UI has its own directory, including .plist, .layout (my own ui description file).
- I put all the animations together into one directory, in which the same sprites may share the same animation.